# How do i mock the "as" statement in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a script that imports a file in this format :

```
import foo.util.foo_util as util
```

when i try to mock via

```
@mock.patch('foo.util.foo_util')
```

It's not able to mock the statement. How do i mock this?

Answer (score 0):

You called it '''as util''' so why are you writing @mock.patch('foo.util.foo_util') when you can just @mock.patch('util')

Comment: nope. that doesn't work either, i have tried it already